# Setting a Regex number range based on previous value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My question is a bit complicated or at least I tend to think so.

I have a regex that validates a string:

**String:** `AWT=10/3:13;`

**Regex:** `var reg = new RegExp('^AWT=\\d\\d/([1-9][0-9]*):(\\d{1,9});$');`

**Code:**

```
var reg = new RegExp('^AWT=\\d\\d/([1-9][0-9]*):(\\d{1,9});$');
var x = $('td').find('input')[7].value;

    if (!x.match(reg)) {
        return [false, "Failed"];
    } else {
        return ['Success', true];
    }
```

**Problem:**

For instance, if this was the **string**: `AWT=13/3:1;`, I need it to satisfy these criterias:

A) Numeric value after the `/` slash must be non-zero and positive (should always start at `1`).

B) Numeric value after the `/3` can't exceed the numeric value before the `13/`, basically it must range between `[1-13]`.

In simpler words is there a way to set a range of numbers after the `/`, based on the numeric value provided before the `/`?

Comment: I don't think regex can do that, but you can do that in the code by comparing the values of the capturing groups.

Comment: I understand `'='` must be followed by the digit `'1'`. How many digits may follow `'1'`? (`0` or `1`? `0` or more?). Is `3` the only character that can fall between `'/'` and `':'`? If not, what digit(s) can occupy that part of the string?

Comment: All you can do is capture the first number and then compare with the third.

Comment: @CarySwoveland All the digits within the string can be of any numeric value. For instance, `AWT=20/3:14;`, `AWT=30/23:100;` are possibilities as well.

Comment: *If* the string begins `'AWT='`, `'='` is followed by `'1'` followed by any digit, which is followed by `'/3:'`, and `':'` is followed by a digit `'1-9'` or by two or more digits, which is followed by `';'` at the end of the string, you can verify the string with the following regex:...

Comment: ...`/^AWT=(?:10\/3:(?:[1-9]|10)|11\/3:(?:[1-9]|1[01])|12\/3:(?:[1-9]|1[0-2])|13\/3:(?:[1-9]|1[0-3])|14\/3:(?:[1-9]|1[0-4])|15\/3:(?:[1-9]|1[0-5])|16\/3:(?:[1-9]|1[0-6])|17\/3:(?:[1-9]|1[0-7])|18\/3:(?:[1-9]|1[0-8])|19\/3:(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]));$/`. [ref](https://regex101.com/r/5YDkDr/1/). If `'3'` following `'/'` is a placeholder rather than a literal, modify the regex as appropriate. You did ask.

Comment: In my penultimate comment please change "':' is followed by a digit `'1-9'` or by two or more digits" to "':' is followed by a digit `'1-9'` or by two or more digits, the first being `'1-9'`".

Comment: @Peter, oh, well. I posted my comments before I saw yours. You could use a regex to verify everything other than condition "B". From the standpoint of the limitations of regular expressions, however, "B" stands for "Biggie". I suggest you verify all but "B" with a regex, use a second regex to extract the bits that concern "B", then invoke JS code to use those bits to test "B".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare numbers within a regex, however you can apply the regex and compare the numbers as in this example:

```js
var str1 = 'AWT=10/3:13;';   // should pass
var str2 = 'AWT=10/10:13;';  // should pass
var str3 = 'AWT=10/11:13;';  // should fail

function validateString(str) {
  var re = new RegExp('^AWT=(\\d\\d)/([1-9][0-9]*):(\\d{1,9});$');
  var matches = re.exec(str);
  if(matches) {
    var n1 = parseInt(matches[1], 10);
    var n2 = parseInt(matches[2], 10);
    if(n1 < n2) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

var result1 = validateString(str1);
var result2 = validateString(str2);
var result3 = validateString(str3);
console.log('str1: ' + str1 + ', result1: ' + result1);
console.log('str2: ' + str2 + ', result2: ' + result2);
console.log('str3: ' + str3 + ', result3: ' + result3);
```

Console log:

````
str1: AWT=10/3:13;, result1: true
str2: AWT=10/10:13;, result2: true
str3: AWT=10/11:13;, result3: false
```
````

Comment: This works absolutely perfect! However, `AWT=10/10:1;` is returning false.. Any reason why?

Comment: Simply a `<=` vs a `<` comparison issue. Fixed example.

Comment: I realized that after I posted the comment :P... Thank you regardless!